# How to center image horizontally and vertically in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

```
<div class="field-gallery">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">
      <a href="somelink"><img src="img.png"></a> 
    <div>
    <div class="field-item">
      <a href="somelink"><img src="img.png"></a> 
    <div>
    <div class="field-item">
      <a href="somelink"><img src="img.png"></a> 
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you can see here are thumbnails for an image gallery. They should float left and open with Colorbox.

Some thumb images are 100px width and 67px heigth. 
Some thumb images are 75px width and 100px height.

.field-item should be 120px height and 120px width and have a border (2px solid).

How all images can be centered horzontally and vertically within this 2px square.

This works fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 11. How can this be solved in IE 11 and < IE 11 ?

Comment: Please include all of your code and give us a working demo where we can see the issue and help you troubleshoot. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There are a lot of versions how to center the image horizontally and vertically. But non of those is working in my example in IE11. You can try it by yourself.